# Get two random separate numbers?

Tags: arrays, powershell, numbers

For Get-Random, how would it be possible to get random numbers and having the results looking like this?

```
'100,100'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the `-Count` parameter is what you are after. Unfortunately you will need to provide it with the min/max via the Pipeline.

```
# String
(1..100 | Get-Random -Count 2) -join ',' 
# Array
1..100 | Get-Random -Count 2
```

More details about `Get-Random` can be found on the [MS Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-random?view=powershell-7).

Comment: Thank you Drew! and one more question, if i want to define that code as a variable via '$' how would i constantly randomize the numbers using the variable?

Comment: @dannyr.gez Just take any of the statement and assign them to a variable (eg: `$MyVariable = (1..100 | Get-Random -Count 2) -join ',' `